# How to host Laravel project on Raspberry Pi

Tags: laravel, apache

I have scoured the depths of the internet for this solution and I come up empty handed. I have installed apache server on my pi and when I access the IP address from another computer, it pulls up the correct index.html page. So the server is working fine. My problem is that I can't get my Laravel app to work. When I deploy my laravel apps to other hosting sites, I put everything except the "public" folder into a separate folder in the file tree, and edit the index.php file in the public folder to match the new file structure of pointing to the autoload.php and bootstrap files. None of that is working for me in the apache server on the Pi. Can someone tell me how to do this or where there is legitimate documentation on how to do it. Please don't point me to any google articles that come up in the first 3 pages because i've read and tried them all.

The only thing that happens right now is that when i go to "IPaddress/project_folder" in the URL, it just brings up the file tree in the browser as opposed to pointing to my "/" route within the laravel project.

Comment: Can you reach it at ipAddress/project_folder/public?

Comment: I cannot. I've still been trying more articles but haven't found success

Comment: you get the file tree you said, what happens if you click on public?

Comment: if i click public, it'll take me to the public subfolder. If i go to resources>views>project_home_page.blade.php, it'll load the html version of that page. but it doesn't load any functionality. There's supposed to be a socket connection established and some other things that never occur. it basically just displays a nonfunctioning html page

Comment: do you have php installed?

Comment: yes, version 7.0

Comment: is it working? if call a php file with some code, does it run? try phpinfo();

Comment: btw you need 7.1.3 for laravel > 5.5

Comment: oh hmm....let me try upgrading the php

Comment: Make sure php is running on your server, because it appears that its not. make another folder and make index.php with `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Did it work? What was the problem?

Comment: Yes, it was in fact the PHP issue